# Fuse tripping current

Tags: current

I have one fuse (0ZCF0300AF2C) in my design. At the input I apply 12 V 3 A, as per datasheet of this my fuse have reset at trip current 5.20 A but in my case fuse reset at 3.6 A.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx6a0.jpg

Comment: What are the load characteristics? Did it trip immediately or after some delay?

Comment: Do fuses 'trip'? I thought they melted.

Comment: How are you sure it's limited to 3.6A? What is drawing the current? How quickly did the fuse blow? What's the datasheet for the fuse?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the PTC [data sheet](https://belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-0zcf-series.pdf) carefully you will see this graph: -

[image]

Your device is the red-dotted line and, it tells you that at a higher temperature, the trip current reduces so, by about 80°C, the trip current will have fallen to about 50% of 5.2 amps i.e. 2.6 amps.

I'm sure you will say that the ambient temperature is nowhere near 80°C but, it's the device's local temperature that is important here and, as more current passes through the device, it gets rapidly warmer and warmer.

So, for a test at 3.6 amps (70% of 5.2 amps), the local device temperature has only to rise to about 55°C and, this is likely what is happening.